# Saleor comes with react by default. Can we have a 'basic' Saleor without frontend frameworks?

Tags: django, vue.js, e-commerce, saleor

I wanted to use Saleor for a "single-type-product" e-commerce website. I installed Saleor yesterday but it has a huge requirements file, including react.js and many other frontend stuff. I don't want them. Is it possible to install Saleor without anything else? Or at least, with the least other requirements?

Comment: you mean to say you just need to use the backend?, like grapql endpoints and your own front end?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simply install the backend and expose the graphql api endpoint to consume data from you front-end. Or go regular django-style and use templated views. Simply clone the repo here https://github.com/mirumee/saleor.git, install, migrate and run the django server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can install saleor only the backend part.
To do so,
run `git clone https://github.com/mirumee/saleor.git`
after that,
create a docker-compose.yml file if you would like to run with docker-compose
otherwise you are good to go.